# Unable to send large files to elasticsearch using curl: argument too long

Tags: bash, shell, curl

This is the script i used to export some documents to elasticsearch but no luck

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -v 
trap read debug
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d);
echo $date;
config_file="/home/p.sshanm/reports_elastic.cfg";
echo $config_file;
URL="http://p-acqpes-app01.wirecard.sys:9200/reports-"$date"";
echo $URL;

find /transfers/documents/*/done/ -type f -name "ABC-Record*_${date}*.csv"|
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename
do
    echo "filename : ${filename}"
    var=$(base64 "$filename"| perl -pe 's/\n//g');

    #if i use below it will fail as argument too long , so i used with curl option @
    # var1= $(curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/reports-'$date'/document/reports?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d' { "data" : "'$var'" }')

    var1=$(curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- "$URL" >>CURLDATA
    { "data": "$var" }
    CURL_DATA)
done;
```

If i use below it as

```
var1= $(curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/reports-'$date'/document/reports?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d' { "data" : "'$var'" }')
```

will fail as below, so i used with curl option `@`

> argument too long

Comment: Can you try adding double-quotes around `URL` as `curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/reports-$date/document/reports?pipeline=attachment&pretty" -d '{ "data" : "'"$var"'" }'`

Comment: curl: /usr/bin/curl: cannot execute [Argument list too long]

Comment: Did using the `@` option work? Any problems using it?

Comment: Yes, but got syntax error .line 31: syntax error at line 32: `)' unexpected `var1=$(curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- "$URL" >>CURLDATA
    { "data": "$var" }
 CURL_DATA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax to read from `stdin` is wrong, the [here-doc string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) should have been (`<<`) and the de-limiters are mis-matching use `CURL_DATA` at both places.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- "$URL" <<CURL_DATA
{ "data": "$var" }
CURL_DATA
```

Comment: It failed again . `var1=$(curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- "$URL" <<CURL_DATA
           { "data": "$var" }
          CURL_DATA)
done;`
./reports.sh: line 21: syntax error at line 31: `<<' unmatched

Comment: @codebeginner: Can you try first without placing it in  a variable? remember there should not be any leading or trailing whitespaces between the de-limiters `CURL_DATA` in start and end